# How to print colored text below the prompt in zsh widget?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, zsh-zle

I want to create a widget bound to a hotkey that prints the current command description in rich text below the prompt, then erases it after a keypress. Like so (simplified):

```
widget() {
  zle -R "ls - list files"
  read -k 1
}
zle -N widget
bindkey '\eg' widget
```

But `zle -R` can print only plain text, it doesn't even support line breaks. I want to print text with color and line breaks like `^[[31mls^[[00m - list files`.

What approaches can I use to do that?

Just printing it to a regular stdout then initializing a new prompt would be a bad user interface for my use case. That would be an undesirable solutions.

I want it to appear below the prompt and work similarly to zsh-autocomplete, ctrl+R, or fzf. The output doesn't have any complex interactions, it only appears on hotkey and disappears on keypress after that.

The zsh-autocomplete repo does similar, but I don’t know how it is done.

Comment: `zle -R $'\e[31mls\e[00m - list files'` doesn't work?

Comment: No, it can only print plain text. Control codes will show up in terminal.

Comment: You said that even linebreaks don't work; did you try with a literal one? `zle -R $'ls - \n list files'`

Comment: Yes I did. If you want to suggest that my statements are false, it's a good idea to test your claims first.

Comment: you provided an example but I don’t know how to use it; btw, a literal newline isn’t `'\n'` but `$'\n'`; because you didn't comment on that construct I wasn't sure that you tested it, sorry for that

Comment: `zle -R` [can't output any kind of control characters](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00100.html), at least that was the case at the time of this thread (which is pretty old to be fair)

Comment: I'm not a master on zsh, but I know a few things. I spend a few hours on this one and I couldn't find something. Maybe an expert could help.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `zle -R`, you end up calling t[his function inside `zsh`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/Zle/zle_thingy.c#L418). The first argument after `-R` is stored in `statusline`. That is [checked here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/Zle/zle_refresh.c#L1382) and stripped of any characters that would [modify the screen unexpectedly here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/Zle/zle_refresh.c#LL1387C2-L1387C2). So the mailing list [question from 2011](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00100.html) is still present today.

Upon review of the hooks and the code in [zsh-autocomplete](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete), I now understand this works by using built in support for color highlighting in zsh while actively using autocomplete.

Since you just wish to have a key binding to display the status line and await for a keystroke, you will need to write (in C) a module to display the current BUFFER and await a keystroke. This will require you to track the cursor position and maintaining the same state that zsh is expecting.

The [example module](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/Modules/example.c) is a start. You will need to compile it with `zsh`, as the build script builds all modules with tools needed to create the `.mdh/.pro` files from the `.mdd` of your module.

Here is an updated widget that demonstrates the various options:

```
widget() {
  autoload -Uz colors && colors
  PREDISPLAY="PRE:"
  POSTDISPLAY="${fg[red]}POST$reset_color"
  zle -R "$BUFFER" "${fg[red]}line below$reset_color"
  print "${fg[red]}print$reset_color"
  read -k 1
}
zle -N widget
```

Notice, you can't control the display of the status line, it has all special characters removed.  The `print` properly allows special characters, but only on the input line (not on the status line). PRE/POST also only work on the input line, and also are stripped of special characters.

> What approaches can I use to do that?

- Write your own module. This is the best way.
- you may be able to use `print` to color it as you wish, but you would need to still make sure the screen positions are maintained as `zsh` expects.

Comment: This answer states that zsh-autocomplete manages to do it, but doesn't really explain *how* apart from "it adds some hooks that do the thing". Can you explain what functions does it use to print the text? I already tried to dive into zsh-autocomplete repo but it's too complex for me to find the relevant parts.

Comment: I think it could be done at least with some clever printing into the current buffer and erasing it after keypress.